# Laravel Queue subscribe is failing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to setup iron queues using php artisan command. Here is what i have tried so far...

Set credentials at config/queue.php

Tried following command

```
php artisan queue:subscribe mailer queue/receive
```

It throws following error...

```
[RuntimeException]                    
  Iron.io based queue must be default.
```

Please suggest a fix, thanks.

Comment: Is this the just-released Laravel 5.1? Push queues went away. "Iron.io "push queues" have been deprecated in favor of typical Iron.io queues and queue listeners." http://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade#upgrade-5.1.0

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the queue instance created is not of type IronQueue, which is most likely caused by not setting properly a queue driver.

Therefore make sure that in your `.env` file

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=iron
```